# Sigmoid computation issue with typeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to compute the sigmoid function and store the results in a list.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = np.linspace(-10,10,10)
y = []
print(x)
for items in x:
    y = 1/(1+(math.exp(-x)))
    print(y)
```

I am getting the following error while compiling.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sigmoid.py", line 10, in 
y = 1/(1-(math.exp(-x)))
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

I am new to Python. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You probably meant to use `items` instead of `x`

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about how looping and basic data types work.

```
for items in x:
    y = 1/(1-(math.exp(-x)))
    print(y)
```

You never refer to `items` again; rather, you apply `math.exp` to a NumPy array, and expect it to work.  `math` does not support `NumPy` arrays.  Perhaps you meant

```
for value in x:
    y = 1/(1-(math.exp(-value)))
    print(y)
```

However, this conflicts with your original idea that you want a list of results.
You do not get a list by simply printing scalar values; `print` does not save the value.

Perhaps what you want is an array of results:

```
y = 1/(1-(np.exp(-x)))
print(y)
```

Result:

```
array([-4.54019910e-05, -4.19117710e-04, -3.88092348e-03, -3.69937066e-02,
       -4.90741721e-01,  1.49074172e+00,  1.03699371e+00,  1.00388092e+00,
        1.00041912e+00,  1.00004540e+00])
```

If you want a list, then simply convert `y` to a list.

Comment: Thanks. So should I assume that the result y will be an array by default?

Comment: No -- the result depends on the operators and the operands you're using.  You tried to mix an array, a list, and scalars without understanding each operation.  You should repeat the tutorials on each data type so you know what result to expect.  `NumPy` has many operations that work on an entire array of scalars, in parallel; `math` does not do this.  Iteration (e.g. `for` loop) is yet another way to step through an iterable sequence.

Comment: Okay. So in this example x is a list whereas y is an array, or?

Comment: I haven't changed from your question: x is still *your* NumPy array.  Look at the output I posted to see what `y` is -- or add a type check to the code and run it yourself.